# Change colors according to the selected language on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

How do I contextualize (language) `colors.xml` file in Android Studio?

This is my code currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#999900</color>
</resources>
```

`colorPrimary` remains the same for all languages.

How do I make `colorPrimary` be black (`#000000`) when the device's language is French?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the `colors.xml` file into different resource folders.. one for each language.

```
res/values/colors.xml --> Default colors
res/values/values-en --> Colors for English 
res/values/values-es --> Colors for Spanish
```

Then, you can override the `<color name="colorPrimary">#999900</color>` on each folder.

You don't need create a folder to all possible languages... If `color.xml` isn't found for a specific language, the default file will be used.